# XSLT 'matches' function: can I combine regex with a variable?

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I've got an XSLT which compares HTML nodes with a variable value:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//section[contains(text(), $interval)]">
```

The `$interval` variable contains a maintenance interval in hours, so possible values are 100, 250 and 1000. You can see where this goes wrong: if `$interval=100` it'll also match sections that contain '1000'.

The HTML:

```
<section>maintenance interval: 100 hours</section>
<section>maintenance interval: 250 hours</section>
<section>maintenance interval: 1000 hours</section>
```

So I need a 'whole word' comparison. This would work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//section[matches(text(), '\s100\s')]">
```

But I'd like to keep using the variable. This doesn't work though, as the variable is interpreted as literal text:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//section[matches(text(), '\s$interval\s')]">
```

I could add spaces to the variable definition, `$interval=' 100 '` but that limits me to using only spaces there.

Is there a way to use variables inside a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `concat()` for this purpose:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//section[matches(text(), concat('\s',$interval,'\s'))]">
```